# Magento 2 Admin URL only showing Text after Custom Admin URL

Tags: custom, admin-panel, magento2.3.5-p1

I tried to change the Admin URL from the Backend from Stores>Configurations>Admin>Admin Base URL.
I changed Use Custom Admin URL to YES and the text box opened to enter Custom URL where I entered the URL. I don't have PHPMyAdmin or anything. I can only access the database from SSH.

Magento Admin refreshed right away and now I only see the text-based version on Backend. I have tried going back to the same setting to disable it but "Save Config" (now simple text button) does not work either.

Please help, it is a live website and in production. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your Magento product root run the following command.

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"
```

Where admin_path is the path you want to use (e.g `admin_123ab`)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried that already that did not help :(. It's really strange because the admin URL never changed, instead moved to example.com/admin/admin but somehow keeps refusing CSS and JS, turning Backend to just Text.

Comment: What shows in the browser console?